# How to fetch the whole properties from the paginated api for filtering in android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, filtering

Suppose in Android Kotlin, I am fetching data through a paginated API where 10 data are fetched per page. Now, I have to filter among those data according to certain properties that are inside the data, i.e. prices, hotel type, and star rating. Now, for this I want all of those properties at once so that the user could filter onto this, how could I get those all properties and make them available for filtering??

Comment: Fetch all pages and put the data from each age in the same collection. Then you can easily apply your filters to that one collection.